How to do a Deep Copy in SwiftData
I have a workout model:
@Model
class Workout {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String?
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) //when deleting a workout you delete all exericses that happened during that workout
    var exercises: [Exercise]?
    
    var startTime: Date?
    var endTime: Date?
    
    init(id: UUID) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

which contains an array of Exercises:
@Model
class Exercise: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var exerciseName: ExerciseName
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var sets: [Set]?    //When an Exercise gets Deleted all Sets associated need to get deleted
    var date: Date
    var workout: Workout?       //it can belong to a work but it doesnt have to
    
    init(id: UUID, exerciseName: ExerciseName, date: Date) {
        self.id = id
        self.exerciseName = exerciseName
        self.date = date
    }
    
    
}

which itself contains an array of Sets:
@Model
class Set: Identifiable{
    var id: UUID
    var weight: Int
    var reps: Int
    var isCompleted: Bool
    var exercise: Exercise
    
    init(id: UUID, weight: Int, reps: Int,isCompleted: Bool, exercise: Exercise) {
        self.id = id
        self.weight = weight
        self.reps = reps
        self.isCompleted = isCompleted
        self.exercise = exercise
    }
    
}

I Iterate through the entire Workout Model in a List and what I want to do is have a duplicate button that will create a new Workout but copy all of the Data of the current Workout that got clicked in the list:
                             Button {
 
                                        let newWorkout: Workout = Workout(id: UUID())                                            
                                        newWorkout.name = workout.name

                                        //this is not copying at all
                                        newWorkout.exercises = workout.exercises


                                        newWorkout.startTime = Date.now
                                        newWorkout.endTime = Date.now
                                        modelContext.insert(workout)
                                        showDuplicateButton.toggle()
                                        
                                    }

Everything is copying correctly except the exercise array which is completely empty, how would I do a deep copy that will copy all of the exercises and sets too into this new workout?

You need to implement copy functionality separately for each related model so you make new copies of each related object as well.
@Model
class ExerciseSet: Identifiable{
    //...

    func copy(exercise: Exercise) -> ExerciseSet {
        ExerciseSet(id: UUID(), weight: weight, reps: reps, isCompleted: isCompleted, exercise: exercise)
    }
}

@Model
class Exercise: Identifiable {
    //...

    func copy() -> Exercise {
        let exercise = Exercise(id: UUID(), exerciseName: exerciseName, date: date)
        exercise.sets = sets?.map { $0.copy(exercise: exercise) }
        return exercise
    }
}

Here I have renamed Set to ExerciseSet in my code for clarity.
Then we might as well have a copy method in Workout as well
@Model
class Workout {
    //...

    func copy() -> Workout {
        let workout = Workout(id: UUID())
        workout.name = name
        workout.startTime = startTime
        workout.endTime = endTime
        workout.exercises = exercises?.map { $0.copy() }
        return workout
    }
}

And then you have a cleaner code when doing the copying in your view code
let workoutCopy = workout.copy()
modelContext.insert(workoutCopy)


Thank you for the answer, SwiftData is such a simple yet powerful tool

Another nice little feature is you can copy everything except the date which you can put as todays date :          workout.startTime = Date.now  workout.endTime = Date.now
